# android:opening new intent in spinner view

Tags: android, spinner

I am making an app in which i have to use spinner view to show some items and i want on click of item it should go to that page. i want when i clicke on spanish i should go to spanish pageMy code is as follows.[image: when i click on spanish i want to open new intent name spanish]

```
System.out.println("test1");
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    System.out.println("test2");
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
     this, R.array.models, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    System.out.println("test3");
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    System.out.println("test3");
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    System.out.println("test4");
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

}


public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {

   }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Comment: Back button in android app? hmmmmm

Comment: Make MyOnItemSelectedListener as inner class in your main activity class. This way you have access to this.
This way you can start a new activity directly inside onItemSelected.
Add a switch case on the basis of int pos, and either start different activities or reuse the same one with different contents.

Comment: another option is use
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); and let your current activity class implement OnItemSelectedListener. This will again allow you to use Activity object directly and thus to start a new activity.

Comment: You have not phrased your post as a question, it is unclear what exactly you don't understand or what you need help with. I suggest you edit your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write intent in your onItemSelected method for page/activity which you want to open.
and set position for that.

```
 @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adaptername, View view,int position, long id)
            {
                if(position==0)
                     {
                        // write the intent for page which you want to open
                     }
                if(position==1)
                     {
                        // 
                     }
                      .
                      . 
                      .    

                  and same

            }
```

Comment: i tried your code but then my logcat shows test1, test2, tset3 infinite times